# How to add Image in java email with html template

Tags: java, html, email

I'm trying to send email in `java` with an image, however, I'm not able to do so, can someone please let me know, why its not working, I'm sending email with `html template`. What am I doing wrong?

`SendEmail.java` file `code` is as below.

```
`    //Email settings code here
     MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(FROM,FROMNAME));
        msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(TO));
         String image ="<img src=\"cid:image\">";
        msg.setSubject(SUBJECT);
         DataSource fds = new FileDataSource("C:\\images\\web_logo_white.0e72366a.png");
         messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
         messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image>");
        Map<String, String> input = new HashMap<String, String>();

         if (msgBody.contains("Summary page was not")) {
           input.put("logo", image);
               }else{
                   // else block and other code continues here }
```

**`HTML file` Where I wanted to add image**

```
<table bgcolor="#f9f9f9" width="100%">
<tr>
<td>logo<h2><font color="#9d9d9d" ><b><center>Company Logo<center></b></font></h2>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I'm sending this `html` file in setContent part of `java`

Comment: where are you using the image string `<img src=\"cid:image\">`? This should be part of html.

Comment: try adding below lines after setDataHandler method   messageBodyPart.setFileName("C:\\images\\web_logo_white.0e72366a.png");
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

Comment: I'm mapping image to html via hasMap @gagan-singh in `input.put("logo",image)`

Answer (score 0):

Stream the image like this

```
InputStream imageStream = YOurClass.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/web_logo_white.0e72366a.png");
DataSource fds = new ByteArrayDataSource(IOUtils.toByteArray(imageStream), "image/png");
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
```